# Override default equation numbering in Beamer?

Tags: math-mode, beamer, equations, numbering

I need to override the default equation numbering behavior.

I want the numbers next to equations in my Beamer slide presentation to match with the numbers of the same equations in my paper.

so instead of equations 1,2,3,4,...

it would be equations 2.2, 5.1, 7.1, 7.2 ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Beamer loads the `amsmath` package, so you can just use the `\tag` command to supply the specific number for each equation:

```
\begin{equation}
\tag{2.2}
y = x^{2}
\end{equation}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply redefining `\theequation` to `2.2`, `5.1`, `7.1`, `7.2`, ..., direct before the equation should do the trick. You can do this using:

```
\renewcommand*{\theequation}{2.2}
```

If you have issues with that try:

```
\gdef\theequation{2.2}
```

Comment: Why the first solution (with `\renewcommad*`) may cause problem?